# Minikube - Is there a way to run Windows Containers?

Tags: containers, windows, minikube

How do I run Windows containers on Minikube?

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I tried it.

Comment: Ok and what happened? I do not see any logs.

Comment: I got an error message, but it was pointless to get it working for me with only Linux containers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not officially supported (as of Minikube 0.25.0, Kubernetes 1.9, January 2018). But there is Beta support for Windows server containers in Kubernetes.

These articles contain more information:

- http://blog.kubernetes.io/2018/01/kubernetes-v19-beta-windows-support.html
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows

Comment: Has this changed since then?